# API connect published api in developer portal test return Can't Post

Tags: api, rest, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management, apiconnect

Follow bluemix document for API connect to create, publish one api to bluemix. While I login bluemix developer portal and register one application, then try to post the api with client id. it returns can't post error log... I can see this error log on both developer portal and api application side.

Recreation steps:

1. Create API connect
2. Install developer toolkit and create hello-word sample api application
3. Use apic edit to open local api designer
4. Run api locally and test, we can successfully post and get api
5. Click publish to publish this api application to bluemix and we can get application url.
6. On api designer to type the the invoke url and TLS profile by using the url
7. Publish api product to bluemix..
8. On bluemix api connect service, navigate to catalog, configure developer portal and invite developer
9. Open developer portal and designer one application, we will get client id and secret here.
10. Subscribe this application to our published api...
11. Then we can test on developer portal with client id and secret.. we try to post but I just get can't post error information: 
    [image: 404Erro]
    [image: Error2]
12. While I try to use get the api, it returns running information, but it should be the notes information defined on sample:

[image: Get]

Could you please help clarify where may be the root cause of this issue???? I just follow bluemix api connect document to do this...

Comment: !!! Please edit question and paste in it the comments you have posted, and format that correctly (see editing help to produce numbered lists).

Comment: @ErimerLin: I updated your question to include the steps provided in the comments. Are you still experiencing this issue though?

Comment: What tutorial are you using?